# Adding classes to all children of divs with a specific class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add divs inside a couple of divs with a specific class, namely `".description"`.
Then, I want that each internal div to have a different class, but it works only for the first div with the aforementioned class.
This is the code:

```
function addDescriptionFields() {
    var i=0;
    for(i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        $(".description").append("<div></div>");
    }
    $(".description").each(function() {
        $(".description div").eq(0).addClass("game-name");
        $(".description div").eq(1).addClass("game-description");
        $(".description div").eq(2).addClass("game-popularity");
    });
}
```

So, the result is that the first div with the class `".description"` has all the divs inside it with the specified classes, but the other divs don't.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `each()` loop is useless, as inside it you're doing `$(".description div").eq(0)`, which only selects the first element in that collection, not the first in each `.description`.

You'd have to change it to something like this

```
function addDescriptionFields() {

    for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        $(".description").append("<div></div>");
    }
    $(".description").each(function() {
        $("div", this).eq(0).addClass("game-name");
        $("div", this).eq(1).addClass("game-description");
        $("div", this).eq(2).addClass("game-popularity");
    });
}
```

A better approach would be to do

```
function addDescriptionFields() {
    var classes     = ["game-name", "game-description", "game-popularity"],
        description = $(".description");

    $.each(classes, function(_, klass) {
        description.append("<div class='"+klass+"' />");
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I was so tired of trying things that I didn't see the obvious answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:
var descClasses = ["game-name","game-description","game-popularity"];
$('.description > div').each
(function (index) { $(this).addClass (descClasses [index ])});